# How to access a URL parameter within Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, parameters, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars as my template language, and need to run a conditional statement within the page using handle bars in order to show specific content. The issue for me is that the only thing I have to go off of for my statement is whether or not a report ID exist in the url(?report=312321) or not. So does anyone know a way of checking a url parameter with handlebars. I already made an "equal" helper to check if something is equal to. I just cant figure out how to access the url parameter.

Im hoping to have something like this:

```
{{#equals urlParameter 0}}
    //do something
{{else}}
    //do something
{{/if}}
```

Comment: When you are using template in your application, or pushing a template in view, How do you pas the data?

Comment: will be able to help you more if you show your full template code, and the code where you use the template

Comment: I just got it, but thank you for the inquires.  I was passing the report id to the URL from a local object. So I am just able to grab the value from the object and see if it exist or not.

Comment: you can also answer your own question, so someone might find it useful

Comment: Ok will do I was afraid to answer it, cause it not really the exact answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

I didnt actually solve my issue by pulling the the URL itself. But i found where the parameter value was being pulled from and checked my statement against that. So it was being pulled from a local.res object that was able to be access with {{report.id}}.